# Where to put this code when moving to Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an Application with this code to adjust a "MultipartConfigElement":

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private int maxUploadSizeInMb = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses () {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses () {
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings () {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }   


    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {

        File uploadDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement =
                new MultipartConfigElement(uploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                        maxUploadSizeInMb, maxUploadSizeInMb * 2, maxUploadSizeInMb / 2);

        registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);


    }   

}
```

now I'm moving to SpringBoot created by `https://start.spring.io/` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HadesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HadesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I think I will not use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` anymore so where to put my old code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that config I believe all settings can be done in the `application.properties`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true # Whether to enable support of multipart uploads.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=0 # Threshold after which files are written to disk. Values can use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes, respectively.
spring.servlet.multipart.location= # Intermediate location of uploaded files.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB # Max file size. Values can use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes, respectively.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB # Max request size. Values can use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes, respectively.
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=false # Whether to resolve the multipart request lazily at the time of file or parameter access.
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Registering a `DispatcherServlet` is indeed not required any longer if you depend on the `spring-boot-starter-web` starter that will initialize the `DispatcherServlet` with standard values.

2) About the configuration for the Servlet application context specified :

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses () {
    return new Class<?>[]{ WebConfig.class };
}
```

You should move this code into a `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation such as :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
     ....
}
```

3) About the multipart configuration, you can set it with Spring Boot `application.properties` :

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
```

> `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true` # Whether to enable support of
>   multipart uploads.
>
> `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB` # Max file size. Values can
>   use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes,
>   respectively.
>
> `spring.servlet.multipart.location=${java.io.tmpdir}` # Intermediate location of uploaded
>   files.

Here is the actual [properties reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).